# Loading and Saving state before going to next page using History.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application, history.js, html5-history

How does twitter implement this kind of functionality? let's say I am at this part of the web page.

[image]

Then let's say I click another page (let's say Dev Ops Borat)

[image]

After clicking that. I click the back button then I noticed that the I was back at the previous page
[image]

and take note that the location of my scrollbar is still the same where it was before. So it was definitely saving the previous state of my browser before I go to the next page.

So my question. How do I implement this using History.js? I have come up is something like this.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(e) { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
    var State = History.getState();
    $("body").css("cursor", "default");
    $.get(State.url, function(data) {
        //Get The title of the page
        var newTitle = $(data).filter('title').text();
        //replace the page with the new requested page
        //$('#main-content').html($(data).find('#main-content').html());
        $('#main-content').children().remove();
        $('#main-content').html($(data).find('#main-content').html());
        //Change the  title of the page to requested page title
        document.title = newTitle;

    },"html");

});
```

This seems to be working fine, however when i click back button the previous state of the previous web page is not the same as I left it.(like in the example above)

Comment: Don't most browsers do that automatically (save scroll position)?

Comment: One thing I noticed with Twitter even if they have loaded the past tweeets(let's say you've reach the bottom of the page then the previous tweets are reloaded) then you click a new page then click back again you'll see that they did not reload all of the needed tweets again.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. is that possible?

Comment: Have you looked into if its possible to store/load the content from each AJAX request by passing it into data: attribute inside History.pushState({data: ... ?

Comment: Hey I am curious if you get  proper solution for the problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I completely understood what you'r asking for, but how about storing the content of each page through the History.pushState - and then retrieving it from State.data.content instead of doing a new AJAX request each time?

So replace your AJAX ($.get) with something like this:

```
var $main_content = $('#main_content');

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function(e) { 
   var State = History.getState();
   $("body").css("cursor", "default");
   $main_content.html(State.data.content);
});
```

And then add the content you are loading with AJAX into State.data.content

```
$.ajax({
   url: url
}.done(function(data) { 
   History.pushState({content: data}, null, '/replace/with/dynamic/urlpath');
   $main_content.html(data);
});
```

If you have javascript functions that alters the DOM ie: show() hide(), you could just update the State.data.content with a global function that you run each time you do changes in the DOM.